Question about John Lee's proof on the orientation preserving conditions for the face maps of standard $p$-simplex
The following is from the proof of Stokes' Theorem for Chains in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. I would really appreciate some help clarifying how to characterize whether the face maps are orientation-preserving.
Let $\mathbb{H}^p:=\{(x^1,\dots, x^p)\in \mathbb{R}^p: x^p \ge 0\}$ be the closed upper half-space and $\partial \mathbb{H}^p=\{(x^1,\dots, x^p)\in \mathbb{R}^p: x^p=0\}$ be the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^p$. Let $\Delta_p$ be the standard $p$-simplex represented by $[e_0,e_1, \dots, e_p]\subset \mathbb{R}^p$, where  $e_0=0$ and $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector. For each $i=0,\dots , p,$ we define the $i$th face map in $\Delta_p$ to be the affine singular $(p-1)$-simplex $F_{i,p}:\Delta_{p-1}\to \Delta_p$ denoted by $[e_0, \dots, \widehat{e_i}, \dots, e_p]$, which maps $\Delta_{p-1}$ homeomorphically onto the boundary face $\partial_i \Delta_p$. Explicitly, it is the unique affine map sending $e_0 \mapsto e_0, \dots, e_{i-1}\mapsto e_{i-1}, e_i\mapsto e_{i+1}\dots, e_{p-1}\mapsto e_p$. In this case, I would like to check whether the face maps $F_{i,p}$ are orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing.
The proof in the Theorem states that "To check the orientations, note that $F_{i,p}$ is the restriction to $\Delta_p \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^p$ of the affine diffeomorphism sending the simplex $[e_0,\dots, e_p]$ to $[e_0,\dots, \widehat{e_i},\dots, e_p,e_i]$. This is easily seen to be orientation-preserving if and only if $(e_0, \dots, \widehat{e_i}, \dots, e_p, e_i)$ is an even permutation of $(e_0,\dots, e_p)$, which is the case if and only if $p-i$ is even. Since the standard coordinates on $\partial \mathbb{H}^p$ are positively oriented if and only if $p$ is even, the upshot is that $F_{i,p}$ is orientation-preserving for $\partial \Delta_p$ if and only if $i$ is even."
I need help understanding the quoted statements. I can see that the affine diffeomorphism  $[e_0,\dots, e_p]$ to $[e_0,\dots, \widehat{e_i},\dots, e_p,e_i]$ is orientation-preserving if and only if $(e_0, \dots, \widehat{e_i}, \dots, e_p, e_i)$ is an even permutation of $(e_0,\dots, e_p)$. And $F_{i,p}$ is the restriction to $[e_0,\dots, e_{p-1}]$, which is equal to $\Delta_p \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^p$ as a set. Also I know that the standard coordinates on $\partial \mathbb{H}^p$ are positively oriented if and only if $p$ is even. But how do I conclude from the orientation that the associated map of $F_{i,p}$ induces the orientation that the face map $F_{i,p}$ induces?
To make sense of the statement, it seems to me that if $\phi$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism between smooth manifolds with boundaries or corners, then it restricts to an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism on the boundaries with the induced orientation as well?
I think this should be true because if say $\phi:M \to M'$ is the orientation preserving diffeomorphism, and $N$ is any outward pointing vector field along $\partial M$, then by definition of induced orientation on the boundary, $(E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ will be a positively oriented frame on $\partial M$, provided $(N,E_1,\dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented frame on $M$. Then $(\phi_*(N),\phi_*(E_1), \dots, \phi_*(E_{n-1}))$ will be a positively oriented basis in $M$'. Since diffeomorphisms take outward pointing vector fields to outward pointing vector fields via pushforward, since $\phi_*(N)$ is outward pointing along $\partial M'$, so $(\phi_*(E_1),\dots, \phi_*(E_{n-1}))$ should be a positively oriented basis on $\partial M'$. Thus $\phi$ will be orientation-preserving on the induced boundary orientations.
If this is true, then I think the statement could be interpreted as follows: First, $F_{i,p}$ takes a boundary face to a boundary face so can be given induced boundary orientations and no complication from manifold with corners arises. Hence we can essentially treat them as manifolds with boundary. Then the extension of the map $F_{i,p}$ described in the text can be written as $\phi$ from the argument I gave above, and as the text states if $p-i$ is even, then $\phi$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism. Hence by the argument given above, $\phi$ restricts to an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism on $\Delta_p \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^p$ with the induced boundary orientation. Meanwhile, $F_{i,p}$ is the restriction of $\phi$ to $\Delta_p \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^p$ with the standard orientation on $\mathbb{H}^{p-1}$. This is why I think the author states the next statement regarding standard coordinates on $\partial \mathbb{H}^p$. The standard orientation $[e_0,\dots, e_{p-1}]$ on $\mathbb{H}^{p-1}$ is the same as the induced orientation on $\partial \mathbb{H}^p$ if and only if $p$ is even. Hence, if $p$ is even, by the argument I gave above, $F_{i,p}$ will inherit the boundary orientation from $\phi$, and will inherit orientation-preserving property.
Is this reasoning correct? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clarify why the statement holds.
